# Spring MVC Controller to Load table in Modal Dialog Box

Tags: ajax, spring, model-view-controller, bootstrap-modal

My controller will return the roll number and student name of a class for a year as List object. And result should be shown as a modal Dailog box. I am not able to open the box.

If I calling it through AJAX way then I need to create dynamically the table . So please suggest the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
For example Bootstrap Modal Plugin, u can activate class 'show' and jstl  :

 1. In spring mvc controller :

    model.addAttribute("student_list",studentList);

    2. in jsp

    <c:if test="${not empty student_list}">
        <div id="mymodal" class="modal show" ....>
        Modal Dialog Box
        </div>
    </c:if>
```